# How can i test a tailrec function in Kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, testing, tail-recursion

Im trying to test the following tailrec function:

```
    private tailrec fun findFixPoint(eps: Double = 5.0, x: Double = 1.0): Double = if (abs(x - cos(x)) < eps) x else findFixPoint(cos(x))
```

This is my test function:

```
@Test
fun testNewFeatures(){
    TestCase.assertEquals(0.7390851332151611, findFixPoint())
}
```

The fix point is `0.7390851332151611` but the `assertEquals` returns me `1.0` as `Actualvalue` i can deduct the function is only being launch one time without recursion.

Any suggestion of how can be test a `tailrec` function properly?

Hope anyone can help me with this. Thank you all in advance.

---

EDIT

The real point of this post was a test of tailrec function for avoid a `StackOverflowError` so, i will post here two simple test, but `sa1nt`´s answer was correct for my question issue, and the tip of `Benoit` was great for simplifying the tailrec test

So, the following functions to test the `StackOverflowError` are this:

Not avoided

```
private fun testStackOverFlow(num : Double): Double = if (num == 10000000000.0) num else testStackOverFlow(num+1)
```

Avoided

```
private tailrec fun testNOTStackOverFlow(num : Double): Double = if (num == 10000000000.0) num else testNOTStackOverFlow(num+1)
```

Test function:

```
@Test
fun testNewFeatures(){

    TestCase.assertEquals(10000000000.0, testStackOverFlow(1.0))
    TestCase.assertEquals(10000000000.0, testNOTStackOverFlow(1.0))
}
```

Thank you all for the answers. Have a great day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR

1. Change your function to:

```
    tailrec fun findFixPoint(eps: Double = 5.0, x: Double = 1.0): Double =
        if (abs(x - cos(x)) < eps) x
        else findFixPoint(eps, cos(x)) // eps argument added
```

2. And the test to:

```
@Test
fun testNewFeatures(){
    TestCase.assertEquals(0.7390851332151611, findFixPoint(eps = 0.05)) // overriding default eps value
}
```

### Details

1. Provide both arguments explicitly in the recursive call. Otherwise `cos(x)` will be used for the `eps` because it's the first argument:
   `private tailrec fun findFixPoint(eps: Double = 5.0, x: Double = 1.0): Double = if (abs(x - cos(x)) < eps) x else findFixPoint(eps, cos(x))`
2. In the test you call the function like this `findFixPoint()` so default argument values are used. So, the condition `if (abs(x - cos(x)) < eps) x else ...` for `eps = 5.0` and `x = 1.0` will return `x` immediately after entering the function.

Comment: "otherwise the default of 5.0 will be used in recursive invocations" Not quite; `cos(x)` will be used for `eps`, and the default 1.0 for `x`.

Comment: @Alexey, updated the answer with your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of method, [**Black-box testing**](http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/black-box-testing/) seems to be the most appropriate. Basically you test the method without knowing the internal details. You must just check that the result is correct for the given input, i.e. **what** the method does. This is what you did. But there is no need to check **how** the method came to this result.

Now suppose you completely rewrite your method to use iteration instead of recursion: you don't need to rewrite the tests, they all remain valid.

Comment: i change the text for more easy one, to test an stackoverflow error using tailrec fun or normal fun i will add it into the question. Thanks for you attention